# Почему пропадают товары из корзины после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Добрый вечер!
Реализую добавление товара без перезагрузки. Вот что получилось:

```
// добавление в корзину
        $goods_id = abs((int)$_GET['goods_id']);
        addtocart($goods_id);

        $_SESSION['total_sum'] = total_sum($_SESSION['cart']);

        // кол-во товара в корзине + защита от ввода несуществующего ID товара
        $_SESSION['total_quantity'] = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value){
            if(isset($value['price'])){
                // если получена цена товара из БД - суммируем кол-во
                $_SESSION['total_quantity'] += $value['qty'];
            }else{
                // иначе - удаляем такой ID из сессии (корзины)
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
            }
        }
        redirect();
```

---

```
 /* ===Сумма заказа в корзине + атрибуты товара===*/
    function total_sum($goods){
        global $connection;
        $total_sum = 0;

        $str_goods = implode(',',array_keys($goods));

        $query = "SELECT goods_id, name, price
                    FROM goods
                        WHERE goods_id IN ($str_goods)";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['price'] = $row['price'];
            $total_sum += $_SESSION['cart'][$row['goods_id']]['qty'] * $row['price'];
        }
        return $total_sum;
    }
    /* ===Сумма заказа в корзине +

атрибуты товара===*/
```

---

```
<?php if($_SESSION['total_quantity']): ?>
                            Товаров в корзине:<br />
                            <span id="bought"><?=$_SESSION['total_quantity']?></span> на сумму <span id="sum"><?=$_SESSION['total_sum']?></span> руб.
                            <img src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/korzinaON.png" class="korzinaON" />
                            <a href="#"><img src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/oformit.png" class="oformit" alt="Оформить заказ" /></a>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <span class="offK">Корзина пуста</span>
                                <img src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/korzinaOFF.png" class="korzinaOFF" />                          
                        <?php endif; ?>
```

---

```
/* ===Добавление в корзину=== */
function addtocart($goods_id){
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id])){
        // если в массиве cart уже есть добавляемый товар
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] += 1;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }else{
        // если товар кладется в корзину впервые
        $_SESSION['cart'][$goods_id]['qty'] = 1;
        return $_SESSION['cart'];
    }
}
/* ===Добавление в корзину=== */
```

Ссылка с ценой.

```
<p>Цена :  <span><?=$product['price']?> р.</span></p>   
<a class="buyitem" href="?view=addtocart&goods_id=<?=$product['goods_id']?>"><img class="addtocard-index" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/addcard-table.jpg" alt="Добавить в корзину" /></a>
```

Вот js:

```
 $(".buyitem").click(function(){
var url = $(this).attr("href"); // при клике на ссылку считываем href

var regprice = /[\d]+$/;
var price= $(this).closest(".product-table").find("span").text();
price = parseInt(price,10);

//Считаем полное количество купленных товаров и полную цену
var total_items = parseInt($("#bought").text(),10)+1;
var total_price = parseInt($("#sum").text(),10)+price;

//записываем то, что посчитали в соответствующие места на странице
$("#bought").text(total_items);
$("#sum").text(total_price);

//url ссылки отправляем методом get на сервер - эффект будет такой же, как если бы пользователь перешел по ссылке
$.get(url);

return false; //предотвращаем переход по ссылке = перезагрузку страницы
});
```

Добавляет в корзину без перезагрузки, но после обновления страницы пропадают все товары из корзины.

Answer (score 1):

Сессии новые не создаются при обновлении страницы?
Проверь, что после перезагрузки содержит $_SESSION['total_quantity'].

Comment: @Get, Не создаются.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что данные сессии удаляются при обновлении страницы? Если да, то смотри логику. Где-то или закрываешь сессию, или создаешь новую. Проверь, записываются ли данные в сессию. Попробуй протестировать запись и сохранение какой-нибудь переменной в сессию.

Comment: @Get, Без скрипта все отлично работает, только добавление с обновлением страницы.
_____
@Get, дело в том, что в хроме не работает, а в мозиле, допустим, работает, после перезагрузки страницы товар остается а корзине. Почему так?

Comment: А скрипты в хроме у тебя не закешированы, случайно? В MSIE проверь, работает?

Comment: @Get, другой сайт с таким же кодом открываешь, там все хорошо. Странно.

Comment: Другой сайт, например, закеширован позже. Попробуй открой сайт в хроме в режиме инкогнито.

Comment: @Get, Спасибо, в режиме инкогнито все хорошо. Я боюсь, что после запуска сайта, у других пользователей может быть также. Связано мне кажется и с кодом это, так ли?

Comment: У других будет все в порядке. Когда ты разрабатывал и тестировал скрипты в хроме, они у тебя записались в кеш браузера и теперь вместо загрузки непосредственно с сайта грузятся недоделанные из кеша. Другие пользователи загрузят сразу доработанные скрипты, и проблем у них не возникнет.
Очисти кеш браузера и у тебя тоже все в хроме заработает правильно.